# vbs find file in directory and print with popout window

Tags: excel, pdf, printing, vbscript, ms-word

I have script that printing specific file, but it's getting hard to make over 150 .vbs files for each document to be printed, 
is there any way to have pop-out window where i can type file name, then script find it in folder and print it with 20 copies.
I have PDF, WORD and Excel files

this is what i have now for them

```
Dim AppExcel 
Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
AppExcel.Workbooks.Open"directory\filename.xlsx"
AppExcel.Visible = True
AppExcel.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut,,20
Appexcel.Quit
Set appExcel = Nothing

filename = "\\MCSERVER01\Data\Forms\Vehicle inspection forms\daily vehicle inspection form.pdf"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.Run "sumatrapdf.exe -print-to-default """ & filename & """", 0, True

Dim AppWord
Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
AppWord.Documents.Open"\\MCSERVER01\Data\Forms\DODD\SMALL CAR DRIVERS\Akira Litman.docx"
AppWord.Visible = True
AppWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
AppWord.Quit
Set appWord = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make use of an input box

```
Dim fileToPrint As String

fileToPrint = InputBox("Enter file name to print")
```

Comment: so just add that to my existing script? im sorry im not good at all with VB

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue please?

Comment: Maybe you could refine the question or ask it in a different, more specific way.. Define exactly what your issue is and where you are stuck and it will be easier to help. Right now its kinda like hey I had a crack at some work I'm trying to do can someone finish it for me..

Comment: ok let me try to refine the question, so as you see I have 3 different scripts one for word one for excel one for pdf that print specific file from specific location, what I need is to have one Script file that will open pop-out box saying "please file name" and when i type in file name for example "report" it automatically find file name "report.xlsx" and print it out without opening excel word or pdf. same like scripts that i have now do they run everything on background u can't even see.

Comment: im stuck with finding the way to get pop-out window that will search for file and choose it for printing from specific folder

Comment: does this give you the popup window i.e. the input box, it should let you type the file name and then you can access it using the variable strMessage =Inputbox("Enter your message","Input Required")

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from my old friend, but now i can't get another part working
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
call main

sub main
    InputName = InputBox("ENTER YOUR NAME")
    if instr(InputName, ".") = 0 then
        msgbox("DON'T NEED THIS AT ALL!!!!!")
        exit sub
    end if
    'msgbox(mid(InputName, instr(InputName, ".")+1))
    select case mid(InputName, instr(InputName, ".")+1)
        case "xlsx"
            call printExcel(InputName)
    end select
end sub

sub printExcel(fileName)
    Dim AppExcel, path
    Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
    path = "\MCSERVER01\Data\Forms\Access2Care\WHEELCHAIR DRIVERS\"
    if fso.FileExists(path & fileName) then
        AppExcel.Workbooks.Open path & fileName
        AppExcel.Visible = false
        AppExcel.ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut,,20
        Appexcel.Quit
        Set appExcel = Nothing
    else

X=MsgBox ("Wrong File Name Or File Doesn't Exist" ,0+16, "Please Re-Enter Your Full Name")

```
end if
```

end sub

so the issue i have now is that i have to type in file extension to make it work otherwise im getting msgbox with "don't need this" 
how i can get rid of that msg and just have default extension as xlsx xsl